# Logic: Structure(/Interpretation) - Model for F?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, model-theory, first-order-logic, quantifiers

I have $\mathcal A(\mathcal U, \mathcal I)$ with $U_{\mathcal A} = \Bbb N$ and $I_{\mathcal A}(P) = \{(m,n) \mid m,n \in \Bbb R, m=\alpha n, \alpha \in \Bbb N \setminus\{0,1\}\}$

I need to show if that structure is a model for $F = \forall z \exists y \forall x (P(x,y) \lor P(z,y)\lor P(x,z) \lor \lnot P(z,x))$

I started writing down the meaning of said formula and got

> For all $z$ there exists an $y$ for which all $x$, either $(\alpha y = x)$ or $(\alpha y= z)$ or $(\alpha z = x)$ or $(\alpha x \neq z)$

1. Is that formulation correct?
2. For the structure to be a model, do I need to find a *single* assignment for $x,y,z$ that satisfies the formula?
3. How do the quantifiers act on the assignment of the variables?
4. For the formula to be satisfied, since there are disjunctive connectors, only one of them needs to be satisfied right? Especially in respect to the variables and quantifiers

As always, thank you very much!

Comment: Are you sure that $U_\mathcal{A} = \mathbb{N}$ and $I_\mathcal{A}(P) \subseteq \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$? In general, you should have $I_\mathcal{A}(P) \subseteq U_\mathcal{A} \times U_\mathcal{A}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Is that formulation correct?

Yes. Your sentence is a straightforward translation.... though as such it does not bring any further insight into what exactly the statement is claiming ...  I would provide some intuitive meaning for the $P$ relation ... how about 'multiple of'? You can also try to rewrite the formula into somethng more easily understood ... how about $P(z,x) \rightarrow (P(x,y) \lor P(z,y) \lor P(x,z))$?

> 2. For the structure to be a model, do I need to find a *single* assignment for $x,y,z$ that satisfies the formula?

If the statement was $\exists z \exists y \exists x...$, then yes, ... but the statement is $\forall z \exists y \forall x...$, so to satisfy the statement you need to consider *all* possible instances of $x$ and $z$.

> 3. How do the quantifiers act on the assignment of the variables?

... not exactly sure what you're asking.  A universal means that it considers all possible assignments, and an existential claims something for some assignment.

> 4. For the formula to be satisfied, since there are disjunctive connectors, only one of them needs to be satisfied right? Especially in respect to the variables and quantifiers

That's right. Of the disjunction with the $4$ disjunct you need at least to be true ... so even if you have only one satisfied, you're good.

Comment: So, if I use $P(z,x) \rightarrow (P(x,y) \lor P(z,y) \lor P(x,z))$? Is it correct to say that $\forall z \forall x P(z,x)$ is wrong (since not all x satisfie the relation for all z) and thus the formula is correct?

Comment: @user452306 No, that's not the right way to think about that.  Disregaring the $y$ for now, it says that for all $x$ and $z$, if $z$ is a multiple of $x$, then ....  And yes, it's true that that conditional is automatically true for those $x$ and $z$ where $z$ is not a multiple of $x$, but there are other $z$ and $z$ where $z$ *is* a multiple of $x$, and so then you need to make sure the disjunction holds. It's the differene between $\forall z \forall x P(z,x) \rightarrow ...$ and  $\forall z \forall x (P(z,x) \rightarrow ...)$